# need help generating pdf containing source code from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pdf

I'm currently studying Java programming, and for some reason we're obligated to print out the entire source code on paper. But as of now, i've got 5,8k lines of code in 64 classes, so I'm wondering if there is some awesome plugin for eclipse, which is able to do this for me? I'll need a pdf or some other document which i can print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/paste was our friend.. So that's what we did.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to copy and paste, go file --> print, on the popup window, there is a select menu in the lower right hand corner, click on that, an one of the options is save a PDF.